# Running rules as a different user

Tags: rules

Is there a way to have a rule run as a specific user instead of the person who triggers it?

For instance I have a rule where, if an authenticated user posts a certain type of content it creates a forum post in the administrators only forum.  But it seems like I'm having issues because the user doesn't have access to post in the forum that I want the post to go to.

The rule works when the application is submitted by someone with access to that forum, but creates a forum post with no taxonomy if run by someone without access to that forum.

Example export:

```
    { "rules_test_application" : {
"LABEL" : "test application",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--guild_application" : { "bundle" : "guild_application" } },
"IF" : [
  { "node_is_of_type" : {
      "node" : [ "node" ],
      "type" : { "value" : { "guild_application" : "guild_application" } }
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "node",
        "param_type" : "forum",
        "param_title" : "New App: [node:title]",
        "param_author" : [ "site:current-user" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:language" ], "value" : "en" } },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:taxonomy-forums" ], "value" : "9" } },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:body:format" ], "value" : "xbbcode" } },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:body:value" ],
      "value" : "new application : [node:url]\r\n                                                  \r\nBnet ID:[node:field-battle-net-id]\r\n                                                     \r\nemail: [node:application-email]\t\r\n\r\n"
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: i found https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_switch_user which seems to let me do it by changing users, which from what i'm reading seems to be the only way but doesnt seem very secure.